Disable screen lock on too many wrong PIN guesses?
My little children keep playing with my locked PC and guess the PIN multiple times. Eventually the screen locks out and requires a restart.
There's the A1B2C3 safety pass which I don't mind, but the restart requirement is simply redundant and annoying for me.
Is there a way to disable that? Maybe a policy or reg. key change?

Isn't the restart lockout only after the A1B2C3 has been done? The children are entering the A1B2C3 as well?

What I typically do if I get locked out like this (and do know the password on the computer, just want to have easy PIN login the next time even without a restart) I clear the PIN using a script (something like https://www.makeuseof.com/sign-in-option-disabled-because-failed-sign-in-attempts-windows/#:~:text=4.%20Reset%20the,to%20do%20it.) and then create a new one in the Settings

שקויעך, but I don't know if they know the A1B2C3, it's just that I often come back to my desk to see it locked pending a restart.
